# What circuit simulators can also simulate ESP8266 and/or ATmega328?

Tags: arduino, simulation, esp8266

I'm going to start soon some ESP8266 and Arduino Nano projects. I've used some simulators in the past, but none of them simulated these ICs.

Dou you know if there is any simulator, that would also include basic passive components? 
Clarification: ideally, the simulator will take and run the Arduino/ESP code.

Can be online or desktop (Win/Linux/Mac), free or paid.

Comment: Atmel Studio for the AVR has a built-in simulator, but I fear this is not what you are asking about.  If you mean like a SPICE type thing, that doesn't exist for microcontrollers.

Comment: Nope. That's what devboards and prototyping are for.

Answer (score 2):

Microcontrollers do not have comprehensive simulation models. You can maaaybe (if you try incredibly hard) get a vendor model for a GPIO block but even that would be an engineer's fantasy come true. Typically, reading the datasheet and doing some characterization on your own is enough to verify the Chip's analog performance. If you're talking about a CPU emulator, that's something else altogether...

Answer (score 1):

[Labcenter's Proteus VSM](https://www.labcenter.com/simulation/) is the only simulator I know of which can read code for several different micro-controllers and emulate them in near-real-time. I'm not sure if they have ESP8266 capability but it is not listed. The price tag for micro emulation and other "VSM" features is significant however.

Personally I would use/design a debug/serial port connection to the micro and simulate any other circuitry as needed ([LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html), etc.)

Answer (score 0):

the Proteus version which has the IoT capability can simulate the ESP8266, it even shows the web page coded into the module (inside the simulator) whith the visual designer window and it also has the posibility of load the page in the web explorer of you computer i.e., firefox, chrome, edge, etc.. For linux users I've ran it using playonlinux whose use wine and there the loadind of the web page doesn't work because a bug where the http protocol is not supported (message shown by the depurator of playonlinux).

NOTE: The version of proteus in was ran it that function is the 8.8 SP1